# Why is the given transformation bijective and bicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

The following is an explanation that I've found on this site for finding the derivative of $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$ using the derivative definition. I was hoping that someone could clarify exactly why we set $k = \frac{-h}{2x(x+h)}$ and then solve for $h$ to come to the conclusion that the transformation is bijective and bicontinuous. Why exactly is that important? And if it is bijective and bicontinuous, how would one arrive at that conclusion?

> \begin{align}
> f(x+h)-f(x)&=(x+h)^2\sin\frac{1}{x+h}-x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}\\
> &=x^2\left(\sin\frac{1}{x+h}-\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)+2hx\sin\frac{1}{x+h}+h^2\sin\frac{1}{x+h}
> \end{align}
>   When you divide by $h$ you get
>   $$
> \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=
> \frac{x^2}{h}\left(\sin\frac{1}{x+h}-\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)+2x\sin\frac{1}{x+h}+h\sin\frac{1}{x+h}
> $$
>   and you're left with computing
>   $$
> >\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\left(\sin\frac{1}{x+h}-\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)
> $$
>   because the second summand above tends to $2x\sin(1/x)$ and the third summand tends to $0$. You'll reinsert $x^2$ later.
>
> Now you can use the identity
>   $$
> \sin\alpha-\sin\beta=2\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}
> $$
>   Setting $\alpha=1/(x+h)$ and $\beta=1/x$, we have
>   $$
> \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x+h}+\frac{1}{x}\right)=
> \frac{2x+h}{2x(x+h)}
> $$
>   while
>   $$
> \frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{x+h}-\frac{1}{x}\right)=
> \frac{-h}{2x(x+h)}
> $$
>   so your limit is
>   $$
> \lim_{h\to0}\frac{2}{h}\cos\frac{2x+h}{2x(x+h)}\sin\frac{-h}{2x(x+h)}
> $$
>   But
>   $$
> \lim_{h\to0}2\cos\frac{2x+h}{2x(x+h)}=2\cos\frac{1}{x}
> $$
>   so we just need to compute
>   $$
> \lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\sin\frac{-h}{2x(x+h)}
> $$
>   Set $k=-h/(2x(x+h))$, so
>   $$
> 2x^2k+2xhk=-h
> $$
>   or $h(2xk+1)=-2x^2k$ that lends
>   $$
> h=-\frac{2x^2k}{2xk+1}
> $$
>   So this transformation is bijective (and bicontinuous) and $h\to0$ implies $k\to0$ so your limit is
>   $$
> \lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}\sin\frac{-h}{2x(x+h)}=
> \lim_{k\to0}-\frac{2xk+1}{2x^2k}\sin k=
> \lim_{k\to0}-\frac{2xk+1}{2x^2}\frac{\sin k}{k}=-\frac{1}{2x^2}
> $$
>   In the end we get
>   $$
> \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=
> x^2\left(-\frac{1}{2x^2}\right)\cos\frac{1}{x}+2x\sin\frac{1}{x}=
> -\cos\frac{1}{x}+2x\sin\frac{1}{x}
> $$
>
> This assumes, of course, $x\ne0$. If your function is defined by
>   $$
> f(x)=\begin{cases}
> x^2\sin\dfrac{1}{x}&\text{for $x\ne0$}\\[1ex]
> 0&\text{for $x=0$}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   we are left with the derivative at $0$, that is
>   $$
> \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=
> \lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{h}h^2\sin\frac{1}{h}=
> \lim_{h\to0}h\sin\frac{1}{h}=0
> $$
>   with an easy application of the squeeze theorem.

Comment: Where did you find it on this site? Can we get the link?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940264/derivative-of-fx-x2-sin1-x-using-the-derivative-definition/940317?noredirect=1#comment6159728_940317